# Google Analytics Client Sampling when over 10milion hits/month

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics Documentation says the following:
    hese limits apply to the Web Property / Property / Tracking ID.

> 10 million hits per month per property
>
> If you go over this limit, the Google Analytics team might contact you
>   and ask you upgrade to Analytics 360 or implement client sampling to
>   reduce the amount of data being sent to Google Analytics.
>
> For monthly total Analytics 360 limits, please contact your account
>   manager or service representative.

What does this mean exactly ?
I know there is sampling , the one which you see in your reports..

But if your traffic exceeds the 10 milion hits per month, is there an automatic sampling system which forbids you to capture all incoming traffic?

In other words : Does google limit your traffic automaticly at the source? Not in the reports but in the source, let's say I capture 20mil hits a month, will i have all that traffic in my property or does it stop at a certain point?

**AGAIN** : i'm not talking about report sampling but about the actual captured data a month

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Google does not limit data collection. You have to implement this yourself, although they give you a [means to do that at least in the Javascript Tracking code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#sampleRate). Implementing sampling yourself would be a little tricky since you want to sample out whole sessions, not individual pageviews.

If you record 20 mio hits you will have them in your property. But at that point you operate outside your quota and Google has the right to terminate your account (they will not do that without getting in contact with you, provided you respond to mails send to the Google accounts authorized to use your GA properties).

So far Google has been, in my experience, very generous even with large overruns, but you should not base something business critical on the violation of TOS for a free service.

Comment: You deserve a trophy for beeing the GA guru at SO :D